# Wp_set_auth_cookie whitelisting for miniorange plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, single-sign-on, saml

I'm facing a critical issue with my multisite WordPress setup.

My site employs Miniorange for SAML SSO integration with OKTA.
Excessive binlog creation filled up the drive space, leading to the app going down.

Looking at the db logs , I can see there are repetitive requests to update saml_session_index and saml_request, which might be the reason why binlogs are getting full.

Miniorange helpdesk suspects wordpress blocking miniorange from setting wordpress_logged_in cokkie, is causing SAML requests to loop endlessly.

How and where can I whitelist the Miniorange SSO plugin to use wp_set_auth_cookie in a self-hosted environment? (Wp site is hosted on 3 linux server, we are using nginx. Database is stored accross two other separate dbs)

Any insights on preventing SAML requests from going into loops?

The wordpress site is customized, I cannot directly modify (install or update plugins) Will have to do that by deployment.